# MarkLogic OS Upgrade - error while loading shared libraries: libsasl2.so.2

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

We are running MarkLogic 8.0-6 on RHEL6, recently we did the OS upgrade to RHEL7 and now when we try to restart the MarkLogic we are getting the below error:-

```
[root@host03 /]# service MarkLogic start
Starting MarkLogic: /opt/MarkLogic/bin/MarkLogic: error while loading shared libraries: libsasl2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 [FAILED]
```

Present OS is :-

```
[root@host03 /]# cat /etc/*elease
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
LSB_VERSION=core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.5 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.5"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.5 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.5:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.5
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.5"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
```

Is it because I am using old MarkLogic-RHEL6-8.0-6.x86_64.rpm which is for RHEL6? If so, How can I get the old MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-6.x86_64.rpm ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you scroll down below the MarkLogic 9 download links, there is a link to the latest 8.0 versions: https://developer.marklogic.com/products/marklogic-server/8.0

Comment: Latest ML is 8.0-8.1, our host is a part of 3 node cluster which is running 8.0-6 version. I cannot upgrade this host because security and schema database is not hosted on this host03. Please suggest

Comment: @Mpathak I'm sure this is not recommended, but AFAIK they do not take down the older images. So if you can snag the download URL to the current version (either the CURL link or from the web page JS), you can modify it to link to the previous version and download it.

Comment: Above issue is resolved. We have added the shared libraries and restarted again and it works fine.

Comment: I recommend reaching out to MarkLogic Support next time, they have detailed advice and docs on how to approach OS and ML upgrades..